# BizUnit - Pipeline Test Steps missing

Tags: c#, github, biztalk, biztalk-2013, bizunit

I've downloaded BizUnit package with nuGet Package Console. I'd like to test my custom pipeline component. According to source respository ( [click](https://github.com/BizUnit/BizUnit/tree/master/Src/BizUnit.TestSteps.BizTalk) ), there is a `BizUnit.TestSteps.BizTalk.Pipeline` namespace containing, i.e `ExecuteSendPipelineStep` class which I want to use.

But I can't find it on my machine.

[image]

I use VS 2013 Professional and BizTalk 2013. What am I doing wrong?