# BizUnit 4.1.4 missing BizUnit.TestSteps.BizTalk

Tags: c#, github, biztalk, biztalk-2013, bizunit

This is similar to a previous question which has been asked (which I incorrectly replied to previously - sorry guys) [BizUnit - Pipeline Test Steps missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677297/bizunit-pipeline-test-steps-missing)

The latest version of BizUnit downloaded from nuget no longer contains the above dll. This used to be in previous versions but it seems to have been removed from the nuget package so now I don't have the ability to execute maps from BizUnit as the ExecuteMap method was in the namespace BizUnit.TestSteps.BizTalk. I've looked in the github repository and the code is there but it's not in the solution. I cannot find any information as to why this may have been removed.

Any ideas?